# Aligning text on javascript menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following page:

http://outsource-plus.co.uk/test2.html

which contains an instant price script. On the summary section i would like the heading **"toys"** to be removed if null(   ) is selected on the list box and would like the **numbers** heading to be moved in its place as i would have no need for toys if the listbox value is remained empty.

I have the following script for the Summary: section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/ui-spinner/ui.spinner.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-price-calculator-pro.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var form = $('#jquery-order-form');

    form.jPrice({
        "floatSub": true,
        "showPricesOption": true,
        "itemize": true,
        "showZeroAs": "false",
        "subAlign": "right",
        "decimalSep": ".",
        "pricesFadeTime": "",
        "emptySummaryText": "<p>Please configure your order...<\/p>",
        "showPrices": true,
        "signBefore": "$",
        "signAfter": " AUD",
    "items": {
        "f_1": "toys ",
        "f_2": "numbers",
        "f_2[]": "Checkbox Group",
        "f_3": "Slider",
        "f_4": "Spinner",
        "f_5": "Drop Down List",
        "f_6[]": "MultiSelect",
        "f_7": "Single Line Text",
        "f_8": "Multiline Text",
        "f_9": "File",
        "q_1": "Quantity"
    }
}
);

/* disable form submission */
form.on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var modal = $('<div class="modal hide fade" id="add-options-modal"><div class="modal-header"><a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>            <h2>Oops! Form Submission Disabled</h2></div><div class="modal-body"><p>jQuery Price Calculator Pro is designed to be added on top of an existing order form, and it does not include form submission functionality. If you require submit via email functionality, it is worth looking at <a href="http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-order-form-builder/485086?ref=BenMartinStudios">jQuery Order Form Builder</a>, which creates fully functional orders forms, and includes jQuery Price Calculator Pro.</p></div><div class="modal-footer">            <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary add">Okay</a></div></div>');
    modal.appendTo("body");
    modal.modal();
});
});
</script>
```

Please let me know if any other snippets of code is required for viewing.

Comment: What have you tried? Some change() functions on your selects should do the trick.

Comment: I've tried assigning a null value to the list box hoping it would do the trick to remove the headings but i was obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit rudimentary, but should get you started:

```
$('select#f_1').on('change', function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == '') {
        $('.itemized-summary .line-item').first().slideUp();
    } else {
        $('.itemized-summary .line-item').first().slideDown();
    }
});
```

You'll want to improve your selector so that it's not so fragile when selecting the correct instance of `.line-item`.

Comment: Sorry im not that experienced with javascript, where would i add that piece of code?

Comment: Anywhere before the /script?

Comment: My apologies but i still cant follow what you're trying to explain, would it be the .json file or the .js file which the script uses?

Comment: Right after $(function(){  or before its } in the location shown in your question would be great. :-)